# ViewController classes when the objects are created

Tags: swift, oop, uiviewcontroller

I create view controller classes and fill them with functions and variables, but I don't have a main that I create objects of these classes. However, my program still works. 
So, my question is when are the actual instances of these classes are created? Who creates them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Apple Developer Documentation :

The UIViewController class defines the shared behavior that is common to all view controllers.
 You rarely create instances of the UIViewController class directly.
 Instead, you subclass UIViewController and add the methods and properties needed to manage the view controller's view hierarchy.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller

---

### Lifecycle events order

1. `init(coder:)`
2. (void)loadView
3. (void)viewDidLoad
4. (void)viewWillAppear
5. (void)viewDidAppear
6. (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
7. (void)viewWillDisappear
8. (void)viewDidDisappear

Here is when the ViewController becomes available

- init(coder:)

While creating the views of your app in a `Storyboard`, `init(coder:)` is the method that gets called to instantiate your view controller and bring it to life. During the initial phase of a view controller, you usually allocate the resources that the view controller will need during its lifetime. In this method, you might instantiate dependencies, including subviews that you’ll add to your view programmatically. And note that `init(coder:)` is called `only once` during the life of the object, as all init methods are.

init(coder:) is like c++ or another programming languages that have main function that create object in the memory

but in `Swift` you wont need to call this method , because `AppDelegate` already do this for you ;)

[image]

Comment: That was quite helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a swift project you get a `ViewController:UIViewController` with **Main.storyboard** where the layout of this VC resides , there an entry point ( Arrow on the middle of the VC ) which makes it the rootViewController of the window , if you want to overwrite it then in `AppDelegate.swift`'s `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`  before `return true` set

```
self.window?.rootViewController = // your custom VC
```

Comment: What am I trying to ask is that these are classes. There is no object. None is created. I mean, how all the stuff works